# Print group by key in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an XElement collection that looks like this one:

```
XElement teachers = new XElement("Teachers",
new XElement("Teacher",
    new XAttribute("Id", 1),
    new XAttribute("Age", 50)
),
new XElement("Teacher",
    new XAttribute("Id", 2),
    new XAttribute("Age", 60)
),
new XElement("Teacher",
    new XAttribute("Id", 3),
    new XAttribute("Age", 50)
)
);
```

And I would like to group by age.

My query written in comprehension query syntax is:

```
var initials = from t in teachers.Elements()
    let age = teachers.Attribute("Age")
    group t by age
    into ageGroups
    orderby ageGroups.Key descending
    select ageGroups;
```

And here is the code I use to get the output:

```
foreach (var initial in initials)
{
    Console.WriteLine(initial.Key);
    foreach (var element in initial)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element.Name.ToString() + element.Attribute("Id").ToString());
    }
}
```

But what I get is

```
TeacherId="1"
TeacherId="2"
TeacherId="3"
```

Without any age. I debugged the code and the age group is null. What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
var initials = from t in teachers.Elements()
    let age = t.Attribute("Age").Value
    group t by age
    into ageGroups
    orderby ageGroups.Key descending
    select ageGroups;
```

Your code doesn't work because you are calling `teachers.Attribute("Age")` which doesn't have any attribute, you need to call it in each `Teacher` element.

Comment: On the write part I was referring correctly to the Teacher element (note the inner foreach loop). But I forgot the .Value on the attribute on the Linq statement. Many thanks